# Hive can't access tables after Spark recreates my orc stored tables

Tags: apache-spark, hive, orc, hive-metastore

When I recreate a table in spark using the command displayed from `show create table mydb.mytable` I stop being able to use the table from Hive. This just happens for a few tables, the other tables I recreate still can be accessed from hive.

I'm adding comments metadata to my spark tables. I do it by recreating a loaded table. I first get the spark command to create a table:

```
spark.sql('show create table mydb.mytable')
```

It will return a create table command like:

```
"CREATE TABLE `raw_db`.`mytable` (`municipio` STRING )
USING orc
OPTIONS (`serialization.format` '1',
         'hdfs://xxxx/corporativo/raw_db/mytable')"
```

I parse the returned SQL and insert the comments in it, but when I recreate it, spark can still correctly see the table, but it fails in Hive. Here is what Hive displays when I run the command `describe raw_db.mytable`:

```
    col_name    data_type   comment
    col     array<string>   from deserializer
```

Here is the complete schema of a table where the recreation fails:

```
CREATE TABLE `sbx_ppppp`.`mytable` (
  `id_conct_cdstrl` DECIMAL(19,0), 
  `dt_cria` TIMESTAMP, 
  `id_usu_cria` STRING, 
  `dt_ult_atualz` TIMESTAMP, 
  `id_usu_ult_atualz` STRING, 
  `nu_vrs` DECIMAL(19,0), 
  `dt_ini_vignc` TIMESTAMP, 
  `dt_fim_vignc` TIMESTAMP, 
  `nu_dia_prz_vignc` DECIMAL(4,0), 
  `in_escp_cnslt_altrd` STRING, 
  `id_fnt_conct_cdstrl` DECIMAL(2,0), 
  `id_avalc_conct_cdstrl_dlibr` DECIMAL(2,0), 
  `id_avalc_conct_cdstrl_autmtc` DECIMAL(2,0), 
  `id_avalc_conct_cdstrl_prop` DECIMAL(2,0), 
  `nu_rlat` DECIMAL(19,0), 
  `id_sit_conct_cdstrl` DECIMAL(2,0), 
  `id_solic_anls_conct_cdstrl` DECIMAL(19,0), 
  `id_anlst_rspvl` DECIMAL(19,0), 
  `id_grnt_rspvl` DECIMAL(19,0), 
  `id_doc_lst` DECIMAL(19,0), 
  `id_dlibr` DECIMAL(19,0), 
  `id_pondrc_escp` DECIMAL(2,0), 
  `qt_entdd_nao_escp` DECIMAL(6,0), 
  `vl_pontc_calc_nao_escp` DECIMAL(9,0), 
  `ds_fnaldd` STRING, 
  `te_pre_anls_conct_cdstrl` STRING)
USING orc
OPTIONS (
  `serialization.format` '1',
  path 'hdfs://xxxx/corporativo/raw_db/mytable'
)
```

I couldn't notice any difference from a table where it works and one where I can't see the schema from Hive after recreating.

How do I fix this problem for this handful of tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that some tables had too large comments. Any table that had a column with a comment with more than 1000 bytes would work in Spark, but have a broken schema when accessed from Hive.

I truncated comments with more 1000 bytes and everything worked fine.

Note that this limit is relative to the number of *bytes* in the string. So if you are using an UTF-8 encoded string in your comments, any accented char would use at least 2 bytes.

This limit wouldn't apply to the table comment, just to the columns.

I still don't know where the size of the comment is configured. Everything worked fine in my development environment, but failed in production.

BTW, in my version of Spark, the `show create table` command does not display the comments.

Comment: This may be related https://issues.apache.org/jira/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/HIVE-4921